# How do I detect when a <a href> link is clicked in an android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, mobile-webkit

I currently have `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url) {` implemented.

However it only gets triggered when a url with a valid scheme is present with http/s or a custom scheme (IE: https://www.google.com, app://XXXX).

When I don't include a valid scheme in the link `<a href="www.google.com">test</a>`shouldOverrideUrlLoading never gets called.

Is it possibly to detect when an `<a href>` link is clicked within an android webview even if the url present doesn't contain a valid linking scheme?